# How to limit number of fifo's users?

Tags: c, unix, fifo

I've got two programs - one of them is generating some data and put them into FIFO and the other one reads this data from FIFO and do something with them. How to limit number of reading programmes? I've think of limiting FIFO's size or checking how many data is inside, but i haven't found anything interesting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fifo pipe is a system file and so the only way you can control access to it is by the usual means (ownership and permissions).  But see also `man flock`.  File locking is not enforceable on linux, ie, you can ignore it, but if you implement your readers to obey file locks, then problem solved.

So: if the problem is *unwanted and intrusive* accesses, use ownership and permissions to prevent this.  Otherwise, use file locks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link count of the FIFO with (f)stat(). If it goes above some limit that you decide, make the reading program refuse to open it?

Comment: I think st_nlink is not what we're looking for. Which field of struct stat is useful in this case?

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski: st_nlink is what I had in mind, yes. Why do you think it's not suited for the stated purpose?

Comment: If I run fstat in a loop and print st_nlink it doesn't change when I run more and more readers.

Comment: @WojciechReszelewski: Yes, for each reader you must create a unique link (say, incorporating hostname and PID in the name) to the fifo using link(), then use (f)stat() to check the link count.